# Identifying power and ground in a PCB

Tags: pcb

I have a PCB from a control box for a machine. It's conmected to the machine via a DB25 cable, and gets power over the cable. How can I identify the power and ground pins on the cable?

If it helps, here are pictures of the DB25 connection on the PCB: [back](http://s1373.photobucket.com/user/Davetal123/media/imagejpg2_zps5cc64320.jpg.html) [front](http://s1373.photobucket.com/user/Davetal123/media/imagejpg1_zps546e59cf.jpg.html).

Comment: Follow the traces, see where they go.  My money is on the 4 pins that are connected in 2 pairs.

Comment: Does the PCB have more than two copper layers?

Comment: Find datasheets for any ICs on the board - then you can trace where the IC's power and ground leads go.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at some of your other pictures, it's pretty clear that pins 12 and 13 are the power supply, since they go directly to the fuse.

And the trace connected to pins 10 and 11 have a lot of capacitors and other things that also go to the power bus (the other end of the fuse), so they're probably the power return (ground).